# Why is windows 7 rejecting my key?

Tags: windows-7

I'm extremely confused. I have a genuine key and CD (I can take photos) and I am trying to install windows on my new tower. I believe this would be the 3rd PC i installed it (old, laptop now new tower). However i did change the HDD once but i doubt windows would think its a different computer bc of that.

After going through phone activation it said i installed it on to many pcs..... i'm extremely confused. I'll be happy to deactivate it off my old tower if i knew how. I already grabbed all the files off of it. I tried to look up the amount of boxes i can install windows home premium on and found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions

What stuck out was this

> Maximum physical CPUs supported[40]    1   1   1   2   2   2

My new tower has 4cores (its the intel i7) but has two threads each so it sees 8. Does that have anything to do with this? But apparently ultimate supports '2'. I'm sure windows support more than 2 cpus so... what gives? Actually its physically one CPU so i guess the number of cores doesn't matter?

Why is windows 7 rejecting my key?

Comment: How did you get the key in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how many cores a CPU has, if it is one physical package, Windows sees it at one physical package.

Phone activation gave you the reason, too many activations at once. You're only allowed a single-machine activation (Clarification: One machine at a time, as many machines as you care to own in series) with a standard Windows key.

If you simply stay silent during phone activation, you should be able to get a live person to assist you.

Comment: Cool, i'll do that. It IS one activation. Except i throw out the old machines (one is a linux server now)